# Ember refreshModel focus on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm having some trouble with keeping my input fields focused while using queryParams and refreshModel: true.

For example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
queryParams: {
    createdAt: {
        refreshModel: true
    },
    anotherField: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
},
```

I have an input components that extends TextField:

```
App.FocusInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
    becomeFocused: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
        this.$().focus();
    })
});
```

And I call them in my app:

```
{{focus-input value=createdAt key-up="createdAt"}}
{{focus-input value=anotherField key-up="anotherField"}}
```

The trouble I'm having is in my focus-input component, as it always focuses on the last field in the list. I can be typing in the first box, then after each letter it moves to the last.

How do I keep my typing focused within the current active input?

Answer (score 1):

Really old but you need to add proper id with input field `this.$().focus();` will focus on every input so that is why it focuses on the last one